# Dynamic Get Clumn value

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to allocate a card to a customer and I want to get unallocated cards number. Suppose I have 2 categories of cards: 1 is visa card and 2 is prepaid card. I want when I allocate a master card it just have to show unallocated card numbers of  master card and same for visa cards. Here is my code.

Model Code

```
function getUnallocatedCards($object)
{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('cards');
        $this->db->where('catagory_id',$object->catagory_id);
        $this->db->where('status',$object->status);
        $query = $this->db->get();
         echo $this->db->last_query();
        if($query->num_rows() == 0){
            return null;
        }


        return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function AllocateCustomerCards($id='')
{
    $userinfo='';
    $contentObj='';
    $submit=$this->input->post('submit');
    if($submit=='submit')
    {    
         $userinfo->customer_id  = $this->input->post('cust_id');
         $userinfo->status_id  = $this->input->post('status_id');
         $userinfo->card_number  = $this->input->post('card_number');   
         $userinfo->card_id  = $this->input->post('card_id');
         $userinfo->print_date =$this->input->post('print_date');
         $userinfo->issue_date =$this->input->post('issue_date');   

         $this->Cards_model->saveCardAllocat($userinfo);
         echo $this->db->last_query();

    }
    $contentObj['unallocatedcards']=$this->Cards_model->getUnallocatedCards($userinfo);
    $contentObj['cardtype']=$this->Cards_model->cardCatagories();
    $contentObj['cardrequest']=$this->Cards_model->getCustomerCardRequst($id);
    $this->load->view('admin/cardsystem/allocate_card',$contentObj);    

}
```

View

```
<tr><td><label>Select Card No. :</label><span style="display:inline;color:red;"> *</span> </td>
<td>
    <select name="card_number" id="card_number" class="medium-input">
                            <option value=""> -- Select Card No. -- </option>
                            <?php
                            foreach($unallocatedcards as $customer)
                            {
                                echo '<option value="'.$customer->card_no.'">'.$customer->card_no.'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select><span class="input-notification error png_bg" id="error_number_id" style="display:none;"></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

But it shows the following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: models/cards_model.php
>   Line Number: 339
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: models/cards_model.php
>   Line Number: 340

row 339:

```
$this->db->where('catagory_id',$object->catagory_id);
```

row 340:

```
$this->db->where('status',$object->status);
```

I print the query and here is my query result:

```
SELECT * FROM (`cards`) WHERE `catagory_id` IS NULL AND `status` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this on the first line

```
$userinfo= new stdClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

This message:

> Trying to get property of non-object

means that you're using object notation on a variable which is not an object.
Indeed, you can find the notation in the two rows (339 and 340): `$object->catagory_id` and `$object->status`. The conclusion is obvious: variable `$object` is not an object.

Function `getUnallocatedCards($object)` called in `AllocateCustomerCards` controller takes `$userinfo` variable as parameter:

```
$contentObj['unallocatedcards']=$this->Cards_model->getUnallocatedCards($userinfo);
```

but `$userinfo` is defined as String type at the very beginning of the controller:

```
$userinfo='';
```

You try to set properties of `$userinfo` on submit, but it's too late.
The simplest solution is the one given by Fabio: initiate `$userinfo` as a class:

```
$userinfo = new stdClass();
```

But pay attention because you're populating `$userinfo`'s parameters when user submits form ONLY. It may result in other problems.